# Extract Video EXIF data using Node.js

Tags: node.js, video, metadata, exif

There are many options for reading EXIF data using Node.js, but all the ones I could find are for JPEG's. Are there any solutions for reading metadata from videos with Node?

Answer (score 2):

How about...?

[exiftool](https://www.npmjs.com/package/exiftool): A node.js wrapper around exiftool, a commandline utility that can extract metadata from many different filetypes, including JPEG, PNG, PDF, WMV, MOV. For a full list see the exiftool list of supported filetypes.

Comment: Thanks Michael for replying. This doesn't work since I'm creating a distributable application with Node Webkit.

Comment: Good luck, I remember perusing through the Nikon-provided developer's SDK for the D3200 with the hopes of doing some fun stuff.  Way too complicated for its own good with a different EXIF format version every year or so.